# RegEx to Trim new lines in a text and append break

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Copying the content from word document with a table.

Copied HTML will look like this below:

```html
This is above table
        
<table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table>\n\n
        
This is below table
```

I need the output be like this one below:

```html
This is above table

<br/><table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table><br/>

This is below table
```

I need to append break for the table element, not a child table inside a parent table.

The actual problem is when I copy and paste the formatted table from Word and Excel of different version the HTML is generated differently.

Excel 2007:

```
<table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table>
```

Word 2007:

```
<table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table>\n\n
```

Excel 2013:

```
<table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table>\n
```

I have written like this:

```
html.replace(/<\/table>\n$/i, "</table><br/>").replace(/^<table>/i, "<br/><table>");`
```

I do not want keep multiple lines of code for each version.

Comment: Try `html = html.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '')`

Comment: Do u only want it where table is ending, not for other html tags?

Comment: html.replace(/<\/table>(\\n)*$/i, "</table><br/>").replace(/^<table>/i, "<br/><table>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mohit 's answer is almost correct, use:

`html.replace(/<\/table>(\n)*$/g, "</table><br/>").replace(/^<table/g, "<br/><table")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Regex, this will help:

```
html.replace(/<\/table>(\\n)*$/g, "</table><br/>").replace(/^<table/g, "<br/><table");
```

Updated the regex.

Thanks.

Comment: Before and after the table break is required. And no need break for nested tables.

Comment: You tried the one which I last updated? Please check

Comment: Let me know where is it failing?

Comment: working only for <table width="200px"><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table> this. Not for the other two

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157444/discussion-between-badrinarayana-and-mohit).